# C# - 404 whith GitHub API request

Tags: c#, github, github-api

I'm having an a 404 response when I try to get the latest release of a repo on GitHub. Using a browser and accessing for example the url "https://api.github.com/repos/python/cpython/releases/latest/" gives me the right JSON, but using C# I get a 404 error. The code worked perfectly yesterday but after trying it again today without changing anything, I got errors.
Here is the code:

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "request");
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Authorization", "token token123"); //token123 is replaced by my token of course
var contentsUrl = $"https://api.github.com/repos/python/cpython/releases/latest/";
var contentsJson = httpClient.GetStringAsync(contentsUrl);
Console.WriteLine(contentsJson.Result);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is here:

```
new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Authorization", "token token123");
```

As you can see in [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.headers.authenticationheadervalue.-ctor?view=net-6.0) the first argument is used for Scheme, `Bearer` for example.

```
 new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", ACCESS_TOKEN);
```

If your Scheme is `token`, then you should use something like this:

```
 new AuthenticationHeaderValue("token", "token123");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, didn't understand token needed to be the scheme, the 404 is fixed but... now I'm getting a 401(Unauthorized)

Comment: Are your token still living? OAuth tokens can have a small lifetime. Try to retrieve a new one.

Comment: Yep, I just made a new one 15 minutes ago.

Comment: BTW there is no releases https://github.com/python/cpython/releases

Comment: Oh right, if I change the repo to another which has releases, I still get 401.

Comment: How do you retrieve tokens? As I can see there is no need in auth for public accessible repositories. Just try it in browser: https://api.github.com/repos/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/releases

Comment: I get tokens from https://github.com/settings/tokens, I just saw some posts recommending to use a token, without using a token I get a 404.

Comment: Have you set the 'repo' checkbox when you generated the token? https://i.imgur.com/dvzI1rQ.png I just issued new token and it works as expected with GET  https://api.github.com/repos/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/releases

Comment: Yeah, I even checked everything to make sure it'll work, but it doesn't

Comment: Please test it with your token. https://pastebin.com/DwR9pLsi

Comment: Tested it, unfortunately still got 401, I don't know what's wrong


EDIT: I removed the line that adds the token and it works!
EDIT2: I don't understand why it fixed because it's the same code as before, but it did. Coding is weird sometimes lol

Comment: @Yot360 - The correct way to ask questions on Stack Overflow is to post a question. Your original problem was solved. Now you have another problem. You should post a new question. Do not use comments as running Q&A sessions.